# Redirect to jsp. Why url is not ending /response.jsp?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have servlet that doing redirect to jsp by:

`request.setAttribute("responseVar",responseVar);`
   `request.getRequestDispatcher("response.jsp").include(request, response);`

Why in browser url looks like `localhost:8080/servletname/servletname` and not like `localhost:8080/servletname/response.jsp`?

How can I fix it?

Comment: `include()` method just merge the content of the JSP in the current response. Read more here [General JSP Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14014/genlovw.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [response.sendRedirect("response.jsp");](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) that will change the URL as well but it will not remember any attribute that is set in the request. It's a separate request.

---

What [HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect()](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) states:

> Sends a temporary redirect response to the client using the specified redirect location URL. This method can accept relative URLs; the servlet container must convert the relative URL to an absolute URL before sending the response to the client. If the location is relative without a leading '/' the container interprets it as relative to the current request URI. If the location is relative with a leading '/' the container interprets it as relative to the servlet container root.
>
> If the response has already been committed, this method throws an `IllegalStateException`. After using this method, the response should be considered to be committed and should not be written to.

---

#### EDIT

If you need to access the attributes as well then try any one option:

1. Send value as query parameter but there is a limitation on the query string length

   Servlet

   ```
   response.sendRedirect("response.jsp?responseVar="+responseVar);
   ```

   JSP

   ```
   ${param.responseVar}
   ```
2. Set as session attribute

   Servlet

   ```
   request.getSession().setAttribute("responseVar",responseVar);
   ```

   JSP

   ```
   ${sessionScope.responseVar}
   ```
3. Change the `url-pattern` of the Servlet itself in `web.xml` as shown below and you can use `include` and `forward` as well.

   web.xml

   ```
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.x.y.z.MyServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/response.jsp</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```

Comment: I've edit post. 
With `sendRedirect` I can't use `responseVar` in jsp. How can I change url with saving attribute in request scope?

Comment: As I mentioned in my post. It's a separate request hence all the request attribute will be lost.

Comment: Thank you. Can you advice the most usefull books at your opinion

Comment: Sure start from [Oracle official doc on JSP](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagx.html) and here is the [PDF](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13712.pdf)

Answer (score -2):

insted of using `include` method use `forward` method

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("response.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

include method of RequestDispatcher include the resource and forward method of RequestDispatcher forward your request and response to resource that you want.

for more help go [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432912/difference-between-include-and-forward-mechanism-for-request-dispatching-concept)

yup but it will not display your response.jsp in url

for that you must have use

```
response.sendRedirect("response.jsp");
```

Comment: With forward url is the same.

Comment: Is this somewhat different form my post?

Comment: check answer after testing what i found

Comment: that your answer is correct bt still my answer is not in such condition that one down cast it :(