# How to handle more than one responses?

Tags: java, servlets, response, requestdispatcher

```
public class Uploadservlet extends HttpServlet
{
    
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        String name="arul";
        PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
    if(name=="arul")
        {
        
        
            req.getRequestDispatcher("uploadfile.jsp").forward(req,res);
            
                out.println("<h3>hello world</h3>");
            
            System.out.println("hello world");
            System.out.println("hi");       }
        else
        {
           out.println("hi hello");
           System.out.println("hi hello");
        
        }
    }}
```

After forwarding the request through request dispatcher, what will happen to the below code? My out.println is not working but System.out.println after that is working, what happened to the printwriter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @PradeepSimha while the String comparison will usually not work with `==`,  in this piece of example code it actually will enter the `if` branch because the code uses a string literal for both sides of the `==` and the compiler replaces that with the reference to the same String object.

Comment: @ARULVIJAY please describe "is not working" a little bit better. Also: where does the request dispatcher dispatch the call to? What happens there?

Comment: can you put out.println("")  before req.getRequestDispatcher  and check if it is still failing ?

Comment: @cyberbrain not working in the sense, i don't know whether the code(out.println, because the request is forwarded to another jsp page) will execute or not but the system.out.println is executed, since out.println is a response, but response is already passed in forward, so what will happen in this situation and the request dispatcher dispatch the call to the same page from where it was called

Comment: @JishnuPrathap  yes it is still failing, but if i close the printwriter before the request dispatcher then it is ok

Comment: Try to use `include` instead of `forward` since you want to continue writing after the dispatch.

Comment: Question already answered

Comment: checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31191237/3651739

Comment: What I still don't get: if you "don't know whether the code will execute or not", how will you know that any proposed solution actually works?